# Where do I tell Apache to use 5.6.23 instead of 5.5.9?

Tags: php, apache

I am having a problem AFTER installing a newer version of PHP with the Apache web server seeing the new version 5.6.23...it is still using 5.5.9.  **Where do I tell Apache to use 5.6.23 instead of 5.5.9?**

I am running a local web server on Linux Mint 17.1

*As reported by phpinfo (both BEFORE installing php 5.6.23 and AFTER)*

```
Apache Version:     Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.17
Apache API Version: 20120211
PHP Version:        5.5.9-1ubuntu4.17

Configuration File (php.ini) Path:          /etc/php5/apache2
Loaded Configuration File:                  /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files:    /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d
```

Noticing that newer versions of PHP are available (such as 5.6.23) but, evidentily not from the default repositories for Linux Mint 17.1, I decided to do the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php5.6
```

After restarting the web server (end even rebooting linux), I executed the following:

```
php -v
PHP 5.6.23-2+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
```

I verified the following:

```
5.5.9 is located here:  /etc/php
5.6.23 is located here: /etc/php/5.6
```

**Somewhere setting "Configuration File (php.ini) Path" will do the trick, but I do not know where to do this?**

Thanks

Mike

Comment: you point apache's module loader at the appropriate mod_php.so file. the php ini files have nothing to do with that. that's handled ONLY by php itself. apache's config is completely separate from that.

Comment: Hi Mark,  "you point apache's module loader at the appropriate mod_php"  I do not know where this module loader is located?  I would think that I am setting some apache directive, such as: "php_ini_folder"...I just do not know where to do this?  Thanks Mike

Comment: I don’t have Debian or its descendant to test and write precise answer. You should have mods_available directory in Apache HTTPD config. I think there should be module to activate PHP 5.6 on the webserver.